# iOS: How to copy HTML into the cut-paste buffer?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, clipboard, uipasteboard

I'm interested in letting my users copy the text they've entered into the cut-and-paste buffer, but I'd like to do that as HTML.

Is such a thing even possible? Or do I need to use a MIME format? (I have no idea.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

The following code will get your HTML out of your app and into Apple's Mail app. The documentation doesn't give you a great deal of help on this, so in part it's a matter of looking at what Apple's apps park on the pasteboard and then reverse engineering that. This solution draws on an earlier [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438759/copy-html-to-uipasteboard) - follow up the links there for more background.

```
NSLog(@"Place HTML on the pasteboard");

UIPasteboard* pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
NSString *htmlType = @"Apple Web Archive pasteboard type";

// example html string
NSString* htmlString = @"<p style=\"color:gray\"> <a href=@\"http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/paragraft/id412998778?mt=8\">Paragraft</a><br><em>Less than a word processor, more than plain text</em>";

NSMutableDictionary *resourceDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];    

[resourceDictionary setObject:[htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]  forKey:@"WebResourceData"];

[resourceDictionary setObject:@"" forKey:@"WebResourceFrameName"];
[resourceDictionary setObject:@"text/html" forKey:@"WebResourceMIMEType"];
[resourceDictionary setObject:@"UTF-8" forKey:@"WebResourceTextEncodingName"];
[resourceDictionary setObject:@"about:blank" forKey:@"WebResourceURL"];

NSDictionary *containerDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:resourceDictionary, @"WebMainResource", nil];

NSDictionary *htmlItem = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:containerDictionary,htmlType,nil];

[pasteboard setItems: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: htmlItem, nil]];

// This approach draws on the blog post and comments at:
// http://mcmurrym.wordpress.com/2010/08/13/pasting-simplehtml-into-the-mail-app-ios/
```

Answer (score 4):

This solution puts both a HTML and a plain text representation into the pasteboard:

```
#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>

NSString *html = @"<h1>Headline</h1>text";
NSData *data =  [html dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *dict = @{@"WebMainResource": @{@"WebResourceData": data, @"WebResourceFrameName": @"", @"WebResourceMIMEType": @"text/html", @"WebResourceTextEncodingName": @"UTF-8", @"WebResourceURL": @"about:blank"}};
data = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataWithPropertyList:dict format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 options:0 error:nil];
NSString *archive = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *plain = [html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfRegex:@"<[^>]+>" withString:@""];
[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].items = @[@{@"Apple Web Archive pasteboard type": archive, (id)kUTTypeUTF8PlainText: plain}];
```

It uses `-stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfRegex:` from [RegexKitLite](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net) to strip the HTML tags.

Comment: To some extent its working but it is giving me the desired result.http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2yw8tqq&s=8#.UvK-rPYkgnU don't know why it did not elimenting the html tag.?

Comment: here is my code http://pastebin.com/Rg4QWUEK any suggestion will be appriated.Thanks

Comment: When you step through in the debugger, does `plain` have the correct text-only representation at the end of the method?

Comment: when i  NSLog(@"Plain Text %@",plain); it show me same result <h2>Word</h2>
  اب تک
<h2>Meaning</h2>
  heretofore/ hitherto             the same thing is working fine when i sending in mail.

Comment: Then the Regex to strip the HTML tags isn't working. Maybe some encoding issue when copying the code? To validate, set `plain` to some plain text. It should be pasted into plaintext fields such as a `UISearchBar`.

Comment: @OrtwinGentz - Your solution still works great. I just have updated one line that was using 'dataFromPropertyList ' to 
data = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataWithPropertyList:dict format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 options:0 error:nil];

Because in 2018 this function has been deprecated.

Comment: Thanks, @MayankKumar, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I absolutely adore this method of creating HTML-based content that you can paste into other HTML-aware apps, like Mail. However, I noticed that the above solution by [Matthew Elton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/531205/matthew-elton) only allowed the pasteboard to be pasted onto HTML-aware apps. Trying to paste the exact same content into the Notes app for example, would fail.

I took the tips from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1078471/351810 and can now successfully paste both HTML and plain text versions of the content that I want.

Comment: This worked perfectly well on iOS 4, but when I tried it on iOS 5, the HTML seems a little broken. I can successfully paste \<a href>\ links, but formatting like bolding and color seems to be ignored.

Answer (score -1):

I use w3schools.
I cut and paste my html code over their example code , on any of their many "Try it yourself" tutorials and then use their "run" button.

e.g. https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp

Comment: Whoops, I use "view page source" from any brower to get the html.  But that is using Windows. Hope it helps someone else.